# ASP.NET mvc 5 controller showing different execution time as compare to chrome dev tool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome devtool shows 6.39 s for `AdvancedSearchPatient` method and asp.net MVC controller shows differently.

Please see the below attachment for google chrome devtool:

[image]

How should I overcome this difference and how can I improve the above difference?

Comment: Remember there is a network between the browser and the server.

Comment: Yes, @Lex Li. But it shows different execution time for same request, then what should I need to improve to overcome this issue.